# Worked out timespan but need to mins 00:20:00 (HH:mm:ss)

Tags: vb.net

Using two buttons to start and stop each using a

```
start_time = Format(Date.Now, "HH:mm:ss")
```

or

```
stop_time = Format(Date.Now, "HH:mm:ss")
```

to store the time and when submitting it uses a timespan to calculate the difference which works like a treat

```
Dim duration As TimeSpan = stop_time - start_time
```

Say if i recorded 00:59:00 minutes, how would i minus 00:20:00?, im guessing it would be another timespan with duration minus 00:20:00 but not sure how to get the 00:20:00 in a format to use this.

Cheers,
Pete

Comment: Subtraction of dates produces a timespan. Subtraction of timespans also produces a timespan. Are you asking how to manually [construct](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timespan.-ctor?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_TimeSpan__ctor_System_Int32_System_Int32_System_Int32_) a timespan for 20 minutes?

Comment: Try `TimeSpan.FromMinutes(20.0)`.

Comment: Why are you using strings? Use all `TimeSpan` types: `Dim start_time As TimeSpan = Date.Now.TimeOfDay`. A `TimeSpan` of 20 minutes is `Dim SubSpan As TimeSpan = New TimeSpan(0, 20, 0)`. Then subtract: `Dim duration As TimeSpan = stop_time - start_time` -> `duration = duration - SubSpan`

Comment: @Jimi - Why not post that as an answer?

Comment: You should try setting `Option Strict On` and see what that does to your code. (If you can get past the initial shock it'll make you a better coder.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of now, you're using strings to store `DateTime` values. There's no reason for it.
 Strings should be used - when dealing with DateTime structure - for presentation only.
Use a [TimeSpan](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timespan?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev15.query%3FappId%3DDev15IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(System.TimeSpan);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework%26f%3D255%26MSPPError%3D-2147217396&view=netframework-4.7.2) to perform these calculations.

Store the start time of an operation:

```
Dim StartTime As TimeSpan = Date.Now.TimeOfDay
```

Store the end time of an operation:

```
Dim StopTime As TimeSpan = Date.Now.TimeOfDay
```

Calculate the Duration:

```
 Dim Duration As TimeSpan = StopTime - StartTime
```

A `TimeSpan` value can be created with:

`[TimeSpan] = new TimeSpan([Hours], [Minutes], [Seconds])` or: 
`[TimeSpan] = TimeSpan.FromSeconds([Seconds]) | TimeSpan.FromMinutes([Minutes]) | .FromHours([Hours])` etc.

Note that the first form accepts `Integer` values, while the second form accepts  `Double` values: when inserting the value in minutes, add a `#` to the value (indicating that the value is a `Double` type) and see what happens.

Create a new `TimeSpan` of `20` minutes and subtract it from the `Duration` value:

```
Dim SubSpan As TimeSpan = New TimeSpan(0, 20, 0)
'Or
Dim SubSpan As TimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(20.0#)

Duration -= SubSpan
```

Use the `TimeSpan.ToString()` method to present the `DateTime` / `TimeSpan` value in a human readable, localized, form:

```
TextBox1.Text = Duration.ToString()
```

Or using a specific format:

```
TextBox1.Text = duration.ToString("hh\:mm\:ss")
TextBox1.Text = duration.ToString("hh\:mm\:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
TextBox1.Text = duration.ToString("hh\:mm\:ss", CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-UK"))
```

> As noted in the comments (and in many other questions every day), it would be
>   a great idea to set `Option Strict On`, possibly `Option Explicit On`
>   and (it can be really useful) `Option Infer On` in the Project properties.
>  This will help a lot in making the right decision when declaring and using your Types.